# Create two rows based on a date time column in spark using scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF with column session_start and session end. I need to create another row so if the start and end fall in different dates.
For ex :
We have df as

| session_start | session_stop |
| --- | --- |
| 01-05-2021 23:11:40 | 02-05-2021 02:13:25 |

So the new output df should break this into two rows like :

| session_start | session_stop |
| --- | --- |
| 01-05-2021 23:11:40 | 01-05-2021 23:59:59 |
| 02-05-2021 00:00:00 | 02-05-2021 02:13:25 |

Will all other columns should remain common in both the rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733054/split-field-and-create-multi-rows-from-one-row-spark-scala

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `flatMap` operation on your DF.

The function you use in the flatMap will produce either one or two row(s).

Comment: I have created a method which willl takes the start and stop time and return a list with two rows of start and stop. But how shall I call the flatMap to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

I did it without flatMap function. Created a UDF generateOverlappedSessionsFromTimestampRanges which does the conversion and used it as below

```
// UDF
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.LocalDateTime

val generateOverlappedSessionsFromTimestampRanges = udf {(localStartTimestamp: Timestamp, localEndTimestamp: Timestamp) =>
    val localStartLdt = localStartTimestamp.toLocalDateTime
    val localEndLdt = localEndTimestamp.toLocalDateTime
    
    var output : List[(Timestamp, Timestamp)] = List()
    if(localStartLdt.toLocalDate().until(localEndLdt.toLocalDate(), ChronoUnit.DAYS) > 0) {
      val newLocalEndLdt = LocalDateTime.of(localStartLdt.getYear(), localStartLdt.getMonth(), localStartLdt.getDayOfMonth(), 23, 59, 59)
      val newLocalStartLdt = LocalDateTime.of(localEndLdt.getYear(), localEndLdt.getMonth(), localEndLdt.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0, 0)
      output = output :+ (Timestamp.valueOf(localStartLdt),
                        Timestamp.valueOf(newLocalEndLdt)
                        )
      output = output :+ (Timestamp.valueOf(newLocalStartLdt),
                        Timestamp.valueOf(localEndLdt)
                        )
    } else {
      output = output :+ (Timestamp.valueOf(localStartLdt),
                        Timestamp.valueOf(localEndLdt)
                        )
    }
    output
  }
```

```
//Unit test case for above UDF
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType
val timestamps: Seq[(Timestamp, Timestamp)] = Seq(
  (Timestamp.valueOf("2020-02-10 22:07:25.000"),
  Timestamp.valueOf("2020-02-11 02:07:25.000")
  )
  )
val timestampsDf = timestamps.toDF("local_session_start_timestamp", "local_session_stop_timestamp")
var output = timestampsDf.withColumn("to_be_explode", TimeUtil.generateOverlappedSessionsFromTimestampRanges1(timestampsDf("local_session_start_timestamp"),
                                                                    timestampsDf("local_session_stop_timestamp")
                                                                   ))
output = output.withColumn("exploded_session_time",explode(col("to_be_explode")))
        .withColumn("new_local_session_start",col("exploded_session_time._1"))
        .withColumn("new_local_session_stop", col("exploded_session_time._2"))
        .drop("to_be_explode", "exploded_session_time")
display(output)
```

```
df.withColumn("to_be_explode", generateOverlappedSessionsFromTimestampRanges(df("session_start"), df("session_stop")))
        .withColumn("exploded_session_time",explode(col("to_be_explode")))
        .withColumn("session_start",col("exploded_session_time._1"))
        .withColumn("session_stop", col("exploded_session_time._2"))
        .drop("to_be_explode", "exploded_session_time")
```

Comment: Please share the body of your UDF for others people that would look at your answer ;)